# How do I use the clang static analyzer with msbuild on Windows?

Tags: windows, msbuild, clang, static-analysis, clang-static-analyzer

The binary windows installer for clang includes scan-build but when you run it with msbuild nothing happens. Even if I do something like:

```
"C:\Program Files\LLVM\bin\scan-build.bat" "C:\Program Files\LLVM\bin\clang.exe" test.cpp
```

I get something like:

```
scan-build: Using 'C:\Program Files\LLVM\bin\clang.exe' for static analysis
scan-build: Removed Directory '....'
scan-build: No Bugs found
```

Where test.cpp is:

```
void DivideByZero(int z){
    if (z == 0) {
        int x = 1 / z;
    }
}

int main() {
    int *i = nullptr;
    *i = 42;
    DivideByZero(0);       
}
```

If I use the following I get some warnings:

```
"C:\Program Files\LLVM\bin\clang.exe" --analyze test.cpp
```

So back to my question. How does one get this to work with MSBUild? What is scan-build actually doing and should I use it or --analyze? What is the difference?