# How-to use Clang Static Analyzer on Windows?

Tags: visual-c++, clang, static-analysis, clang-static-analyzer

I'm currently trying to integrate the [Clang Static Analyzer](https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org) v9.0.1 into my [CMake](https://cmake.org) v3.16.5 build system using the Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler (MSVC) v19.25.28610.4 on a Windows v10.0.18363.720 operating system.

Everything is build for the architecture x86_64. LLVM and Clang have been build from source.

After some reading on the World Wide Web (WWW), there seems to be multiple ways to use the Clang Static Analyzer. Sadly the documentation is horrible and there seems to be some special quirks on a Windows operating system (mostly related to `clang-cl`), therefore it is not straight-forward to integrate. IMO, it shouldn't take a professional programmer longer than one hour to integrate this into the C++ defacto standard build system.

There seems to be at least five possibilities to invoke the Clang Static Analyzer:

1. `scan-build` script.

   - Requires a Perl runtime environment.
   - Is able to analyze multiple files with one invocation.
   - Is able to generate HTML (more advance than the other possibilities), plist or sarif output file(s).
   - **My issue:** Does not detect any bugs, always printing `scan-build: No bugs found.` to STDOUT.
2. `clang-check` executable.

   - Requires a JSON compilation database file `compile_commands.json`.
   - Is able to analyze multiple files with one invocation.
   - Should be able to generate HTML report file(s). by the means of the `--extra-arg` argument.
   - **My issue:** Unable to make it work (refer to the second script below).
3. `clang`/ `clang++` executables.

   - Is able to analyze one file with one invocation.
   - **My issue**: Basically works, but looks like the worst possibility to me (due to missing build information).
4. `c++-analyzer.bat` / `ccc-analyzer.bat` batch scripts.

   - Does seem to support Clang and GCC only.
   - **My issue**: I'm unable to find **any** documentation for these scripts.
5. `clang-tidy` executable with `clang-analyzer-*` checks only.

   - Can use a JSON compilation database file `compile_commands.json`.
   - Is able to analyze multiple files with one invocation.
   - **My issue**: Is not able to generate HTML report file(s), but YAML only.

Here are three batch scripts, one for each of the first three approaches:

1. `scan-build-example.cmd`

   ```
   @echo off
   setlocal
   cls

   rem Configure
   call scan-build.bat^
    -v^
    -v^
    -v^
    -analyze-headers^
    --force-analyze-debug-code^
    -o _scan_build_out^
    --keep-cc^
    --html-title="Scan Build Example"^
    --show-description^
    --use-cc="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\bin\Hostx64\x64\cl.exe"^
    --use-c++="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\bin\Hostx64\x64\cl.exe"^
    -stats^
    -maxloop 4^
    -internal-stats^
    --use-analyzer="E:\dev\native\llvm\llvm-9.0.1\Release\static\x64-windows-msvc1924-v142\bin\clang.exe"^
    -analyzer-config stable-report-filename=true^
    -enable-checker core,cplusplus,deadcode,nullability,optin,osx,security,unix,valist^
    cmake^
    -S "D:\cmake\cmake-example-clang-static-analyzer"^
    -B "D:\cmake\cmake-example-clang-static-analyzer\_scan-build"^
    -G "Ninja"^
    -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:PATH="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\bin\Hostx64\x64\cl.exe"^
    -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:PATH="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\bin\Hostx64\x64\cl.exe"^
    -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Debug

   rem Build
   call scan-build.bat^
    -v^
    -v^
    -v^
    -analyze-headers^
    --force-analyze-debug-code^
    -o _scan_build_out^
    --keep-cc^
    --html-title="Scan Build Example"^
    --show-description^
    --use-cc="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\bin\Hostx64\x64\cl.exe"^
    --use-c++="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\bin\Hostx64\x64\cl.exe"^
    -stats^
    -maxloop 4^
    -internal-stats^
    --use-analyzer="E:\dev\native\llvm\llvm-9.0.1\Release\static\x64-windows-msvc1924-v142\bin\clang.exe"^
    -analyzer-config stable-report-filename=true^
    -enable-checker core,cplusplus,deadcode,nullability,optin,osx,security,unix,valist^
    cmake^
    --build "D:\cmake\cmake-example-clang-static-analyzer\_scan-build"^
    --config Debug
   ```
2. `clang-check-example.cmd`

   ```
   @echo off
   setlocal
   cls

   set out_dir=%~dp0.\_clang_check_out

   mkdir "%out_dir%" > nul 2>&1

   rem Issue: "warning: could not create file in 'main.plist': no such file or directory"
   clang-check^
    -analyze^
    -extra-arg=-Xclang^
    -extra-arg=-analyzer-config^
    -extra-arg=-Xclang^
    -extra-arg=add-pop-up-notes=true,mode=deep^
    -extra-arg=-Xclang^
    -extra-arg=-analyzer-checker=core,cplusplus,deadcode,nullability,optin,osx,security,unix,valist^
    -extra-arg=-Xclang^
    -extra-arg=-analyzer-output=html^
    -extra-arg=-o=%out_dir%^
    -p "D:\cmake\cmake-example-clang-static-analyzer\_build"^
    "D:\cmake\cmake-example-clang-static-analyzer\app\main.cpp"
   ```
3. `clang_analyze-example.cmd`

   ```
   @echo off
   setlocal
   cls

   set out_dir=%~dp0.\_clang_analyzer_out

   mkdir "%out_dir%"
   clang++^
    --analyze^
    -Xanalyzer^
    -analyzer-checker=core,cplusplus,deadcode,nullability,optin,osx,security,unix,valist^
    -Xanalyzer^
    -analyzer-output=html^
    -o "%out_dir%"^
    -I"D:\cmake\cmake-example-clang-static-analyzer\src"^
    "D:\cmake\cmake-example-clang-static-analyzer\app\main.cpp
   ```

My questions are:

1. How-to make `scan-build.bat` work on Windows (I tried both using MSVC and Clang)?
2. How-to pass the options to `clang-check.exe` to make it create HTML output files and get rid of the `warning: could not create file in 'main.plist': no such file or directory` warning?
3. Can be using `clang.exe`/ `clang++.exe` a suitable alternative (imo, its missing the build information that should be available with the other two non-working alternatives)?

In general: What's the easiest way to generate a HTML report with the Clang Static Analyzer using MSVC on Windows?

Related questions:

- [How to make the Clang Static Analyzer output its working from command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22371789/how-to-make-the-clang-static-analyzer-output-its-working-from-command-line)
- [Clang Static Analyzer doesn't find the most basic problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42696759/clang-static-analyzer-doesnt-find-the-most-basic-problems)
- [How do I use the clang static analyzer with msbuild on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49805188/how-do-i-use-the-clang-static-analyzer-with-msbuild-on-windows)
- [scan-build make does not detect any bugs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38308269/scan-build-make-does-not-detect-any-bugs)

Changelog:

- 2020-03-20T12:06Z

  - Update `clang-check-example.cmd` script.
- 2020-03-20T08:50Z

  - Add mention of `clang-tidy`.

Comment: If the program does not require windows headers, you can run clang-tidy from MSYS2

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32280717/cmake-clang-tidy-or-other-script-as-custom-target Instead of launching the compiler in CMake, let it launch clang-tidy instead.

Comment: A potentially helpful link on how to use llvm related software in visual studio
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zMrP8heIz3g